# how to laravel encrypt on jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, encryption

I'm appending a form when I click on a buttom, so I want to encrypt in the form the id of the row to edit.
So I have tried like this:

```
var txt1 = "<tr class='warning'><td>";
var text = txt1.concat(data[0].nombre,"</td><td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign btn-lg'></span></td><td><button type='button' id='",data[0].id,"' class='btn btn-info edit' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Editar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></td><td><a href='",url2,"'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Borrar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></a></td></tr><tr><td  colspan='5' style='padding:0;' class='info-",lastid, "' data-course= ",<?php echo Crypt::encrypt(",data[0].id, "))); ?>></td></tr>");
$(".publics").append(text);
```

But it encrypt `",data[0].id,"` textually, not the value stored on `data[0].id`.

How can I encrypt the value?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you trying to use a php function on a javascript variable? Because that's quite impossible.

Comment: if it's already been sent to browser it won't do any good to encrypt it with javascript, it's to late , you've already exposed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't fully understand how javascript and PHP play together.

PHP runs on your webserver. It takes an incoming request sent from a browser on the client machine. Hands it over to PHP/Laravel. Laravel the handles routing etc. and runs the code in the template file. i.e. executes `Crypt::encrypt(",data[0].id, ")`. At this point the string `",data[0].id, "` is already encrypted i.e. all scrambled up.
Then PHP send a response back to the client machine, where the browser executes the javascript. Which means the browser does not get chance to encrypt the string. It can't even execute PHP code.

Your only option would be to use a javascript library to encrypt the id. You can not use PHP code, if the id changes dynamically.

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but please note that encrypting in javascript is pretty much pointless because the unencrypted data may already have been intercepted whilst transferring to the browser.

Comment: I assumed the id is entered by the user, but if it is not, you are right. In any case, the whole question just seems off. Just ditch the whole thing and use ssl

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, there is other form to send an invisible variable? Thanks